# Ionic 5(Angular9)-Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'profile'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

> I am encounter this erro when trying to click on Home -> toggle menu and navigate to "Profile" .I've try multiple approcah yet still same erro .please help me

[image]

App-routig.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile/',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then( m => m.ProfilePageModule)
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```js
app.component.ts

export class AppComponent {
  navigate : any;                       //new added for toggle menu

        this.sideMenu();          //new added for toggle menu
    this.initializeApp();
  }
}
sideMenu() {                    //new added for toggle menu
  this.navigate =   
  [  
  { 
  title : 'Home',
  url   : './home',
  icon  : 'home-outline' ,
  //icons : 'home-outline',
  },
  { 
    title : 'Profile',
    url   : './profile',
    icon  : 'person-circle-outline' ,
    },
];
```

app.module.ts

[image]

Comment: Assuming your importing `AppRoutingModule` in your `AppModule`, can you provide the code to your `AppModule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route path is wrong. Maybe just a typo. Remove the extra forward slash `/` for profile path.

```
{
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then( m => m.ProfilePageModule)
},
```

Comment: Hi sir,

path: 'profile',             // Instead of 'profile/'    => this already comment out

Comment: The path you provided in your code is `'profile/'` but it should be `'profile'`. I have updated answer

Comment: Thanks Sir , appreviate  I 'm sorry for overlook such a low level mistake